# Restinction on values for operator+ overload in templated class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm doing some practice with templates and I'm stuck with this problem. I have a class that represent a counter with underlying type and starting value specified compile-time. I want to support arithmetic operators between counters type and between the integral types that have a proper type. For example, I want to refuse compile-time the sum of a counter with an `uint8_t` as underlying type with a variable of type `int`. So far so good.

What I obtain is that even an operation that should be correct doesn't compile. Here the main parts to show the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>


template <typename Source, typename Dest, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Source>::value && std::is_integral<Dest>::value, int> =0>
struct type_not_narrow{
    static constexpr bool value= std::numeric_limits<Source>::max() <= std::numeric_limits<Dest>::max();
};

template<typename T, T N, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, int> =0>
class basic_counter{
    T cnt;
    basic_counter(T initializer): cnt(initializer){}
public:

    basic_counter(): cnt(N){};
    template <typename T1, T1 N1, typename T2, T2 N2>
    friend basic_counter<typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type, N1+N2> operator+(const basic_counter<T1, N1>& lhs,
                                                                              const basic_counter<T2, N2>& rhs);

    template <typename X, typename U, U M, std::enable_if_t<type_not_narrow<X, U>::value, int>>
    friend basic_counter<U,M> operator+(const basic_counter<U, M> lhs, const X step);

    operator T() const{
        return cnt;
    }
};
template <typename T1, T1 N1, typename T2, T2 N2>
basic_counter<typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type, N1+N2> operator+(const basic_counter<T1, N1>& lhs,
                                                                       const basic_counter<T2, N2>& rhs){
    return {lhs.cnt+rhs.cnt};
}
template<typename X, typename T, T N, std::enable_if_t<type_not_narrow<X, T>::value, int> =0>
basic_counter<T,N> operator+(const basic_counter<T, N> lhs, const X step){
    basic_counter<T,N> c=lhs;
    c.cnt+=step;
    return c;
}


int main() {


    basic_counter<unsigned long int, 1> c1;
    basic_counter<unsigned long int, 2> c2;
    basic_counter<unsigned long int, 3> c3=c2+c1;
    unsigned long int ul=5;
    int i=5;
    char ch=5;
    basic_counter<unsigned long int, 2> c4=c2+5;
    basic_counter<unsigned long int, 2> c5=c2+i;
    basic_counter<unsigned long int, 2> c5bis=c2+ch;
    basic_counter<unsigned long int, 2> c6=c2+ul;


    //should not compile due to narrowing (and it's correct)
    //basic_counter<unsigned long int, 2> c7=c2+5.2;
    //basic_counter<uint8_t,0> c8;
    //c8=c8+i;

    basic_counter<uint8_t,0> c9;
    //this should compile
    c9=c9+1;
    //this should not
    c9=c9+2000;

    return 0;
}
```

For the last line, I would like it to compile if the integral operand can successfully be converted to a type that doesn't narrow. For example adding 1 should compile, while adding 2000 should not, as 1 can be represented with a `uint8_t` and 2000 can't.

Comment: Which C++ standard are you targeting? The last won't be possible unless you have serious `constexpr` support (read C++14 and above)

Comment: You have a simple mistake: `<` instead of `<=` in the narrowing trait. Also the line `basic_counter<uint8_t,0> c9=c9+1;` would cause undefined behavior in any case. You are not allowed to use an indeterminate value (value before initialization is completed) of an `uint8_t` in C++17 and before and in C++20 accessing a variable's value in its own initializer will be UB in all cases.

Comment: Ok, thanks @walmut for the correction. Regarding what you said about UB in that lines, you're right I quickly changed the code when writing this question to take less space without paying the right attention to what I was doing. I will brake again into definition and assignment.

Comment: @DanielJour can you explain better what you mean by "serious `constexpr` support"?

Comment: The line marked `//this should compile, but it doesn't` does compile for me in gcc 7.4. Was that fixed by the edit made in response to @walnut 's comment?

Comment: @parktomatomi That was why I made the comment. `<=` should have fixed that line, `type_not_narrow<unsigned long, unsigned long>` didn't work correctly with `<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you correct the undefined behavior mentioned in the comments, this expression:

```cpp
    c9=c9+1;
```

fails to compile because 1 is an `int` literal. The compiler throws out some odd errors for this because it tries to make the whole thing work by invoking the implicit cast operator to convert `c9` to an integer, and calling the private value constructor.

So this line would work:

```cpp
    basic_counter<uint8_t,0> c10=c9+uint8_t(1);
```

Which is an awkward compromise you have to have, because it's still impossible to use the value of a function parameter for template arguments and static asserts (unless [P1045R1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1045r1.html) gets adopted).

Comment: I think the important bit here is that every integer literal, no matter how small, has at least the integer rank of `int`. You cannot write a an integer literal of lower rank (e.g. `uint8_t`) without a cast. You could probably define a *numeric literal operator template* that returns integer types of lower rank with a user-defined literal, though.

Comment: Ok, I see what is the "problem". @parktomatomi I avoided in the first place the idea of an explicit cast in the form suggested, mainly because it doesn't address correctly the problem of conversion of literal value. It would be up to the user to not write ` (uint8_t)2000; `.
I looked up for the _numeric literal operator template_ @walnut: it's a little bit strange but seems to be the only solution.
The proposal linked is very interesting, but I see that is very recent, so I suppose we will wait to see it in the standard.

Comment: @Zack The user shouldn't use `(uint8_t)2000` or `uint8_t(2000)` in the first place. If the user always chooses construction of the temporary with braces, i.e. `uint8_t{2000}` then they are guaranteed to get a diagnostic when the conversion is narrowing. This is always true, not only for literals: Initialization with braces does not allow narrowing of arguments (GCC is the only compiler out of GCC/Clang/MSVC that only *warns* about this by-default, all others give an error by-default). You could actually use that fact in your functions. It would be more reliable than your custom trait.